# concurrent access and free of heap object

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency

This question is a possible sub problem to this [concurrent access and free of a data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115876/concurrent-access-and-free-of-a-data-structure)

The other question is open to design, this one is more concrete.

```
struct ds
{
   int x,y,z;       
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
};
```

I need a deterministic solution via which I can concurrently access 1 object of type ds and free it.

Constrains:

1. You can make mutex a pointer but can't take it out of the object.

The real problem:

Free can't be done holding the lock because, then memory occupied by the lock is also lost.

I have read lot of papers and articles on ref counting, but each one of them keeps a lock outside the ds. I want a solution where I can keep a lock or reference to the lock inside the ds.

Comment: I guess the problem boils down to ensuring that there are no external references to the object, at the time of doing free. So if the external references is a pointer we will need another lock outside the ds to ensure the object is not gone. This is why they invented shared_ptr in boost.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that "mutex can be a pointer", you could do something like this:

```
struct ds { pthread_mutex_t * mutex; /* ... */ };

struct ds * create_ds()
{
    struct ds * p = calloc(1, sizeof(struct ds));
    pthread_mutex_t * q = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_mutex_init(q, NULL);
    ds->mutex = q;
    return p;
}

void free_ds(struct ds * p)
{
    pthread_mutex_t * q = p->mutex;
    pthread_mutex_lock(q);
    free(p);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(q);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(q);
    free(q);
}
```

In my opinion, though, destroying an object is not really something that fits the concurrent-access/synchronization idiom. If you destroy something, it's no longer there, so all threads are affected by this. How is a thread supposed to know whether a given `ds` pointer still points to something valid?

Instead, you should probably have a *collection* of `ds` objects somewhere, and insert/erase access to that collection should have its own, separate, collection-wide mutex. Everytime a thread wants to obtain a reference to an object in the collection, it should do so under guard of a mutex, and the collection should know who is currently holding references.

Comment: The code in `free_ds` is still unsafe: what if the mutex destruction is done while another thread that has an address of the same `struct ds` instance tries to access it?

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: As I said in the final two paragraphs, I don't think that you can use an element-mutex to guard against *container* mutation, and so freeing an element really should be guarded by someone else, not the element itself.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am of the same opinion that this problem is unsolvable whether mutex or its pointer is inside the data structure. I think there might be some solution using atomic CAS instruction / hazard pointer as suggested by someone in the original problem.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov I am hopeful we can workout some solution using reference counting. We are free to constrain the users to use the ds in particular way there by ensuring that no one can make an illegal access. The solution is not apparent to me, and my hopes are bordering on pessimism!